# How do I solve an error in Visual Studio C++ 'xmemory' file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In my project, I had an error with a vector that I solved by including this line in the header file:

`std::vector<std::vector<int, int>, int> cells;`

However, this produced 181 errors, all of them found either in the 'vector' file or the 'xmemory' file. How do I fix these errors?
The first of these errors is: `'_Alloc': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'`

My two files:

**Cells.cpp**

```
#include "Cells.h"
#include <vector>

vector<vector<int, int>, int> cells;    // [[x, y], state]

// initiates the list of cells
void Cells::init(int w, int h, int s) {
    cells.clear();
    for (int y = s; y <= h; y += s) {
        for (int x = s; x <= w; x += s) {
            cells.push_back({ x, y }, 0);
        }
    }
}


// finds the index of a cell given its coordinates
int find(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) {
        if (cells[i][0] == { x, y }) {
            return i
        }
    }
}

void Cells::setState(int x, int y, int s) {
    cells[find(x, y)][1] = s;
}

// the logic of the game
int Cells::brain(int x, int y, int s) { // 1 alive 0 dead, s = size + space
    vector<int, int, int, int> around;
    int tAlive;

    // getting the states of all the cells in a 1 cell radius around the focused one
    around.push_back(cells[find(x - s, y - s)][1]);
    around.push_back(cells[find(x, y - s)][1]);
    around.push_back(cells[find(x + s, y - s)][1]);
    around.push_back(cells[find(x - s, y)][1]);
    around.push_back(cells[find(x + s, y)][1]);
    around.push_back(cells[find(x - s, y + s)][1]);
    around.push_back(cells[find(x, y + s)][1]);
    around.push_back(cells[find(x + s, y + s)][1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (around[i] == 1) {
            tAlive++;
        }
    }

    if (cells[find(x, y)][1] == 1) {
        if (tAlive <= 1 || tAlive >= 4) {
            cells[find(x, y)][1] = 0;
        } else {
            cells[find(x, y)][1] = 1;
        }
    } else {
        if (tAlive == 3) {
            cells[find(x, y)][1] = 1;
        }
    }

    return cells[find(x, y)][1];
}
```

**Cells.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class Cells {
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<int, int>, int> cells;
    void init(int w, int h, int s);
    int brain(int x, int y, int s);
    void setState(int x, int y, int s);
};
```

Comment: `vector<vector<int, int>, int> cells;` - there is no `vector`, There is only `std::vector`. You're missing something. Not sure why that's there in the first place, since you have a member by the same name.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly, with those vector template parameters? Why not use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`? If you're trying to store pairs, then use `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>`

Comment: `int` is not an allocator, hence `vector<int, int>` as well as `vector<vector<int, int>, int>` fail to compile. Did you mean `vector<vector<int>>`?

Comment: I'm trying to make a list that would look like this [ [0, 0] 0, [1, 1] 1]

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int,int>, int>>`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, vector> isn’t allowed before C++11 standard. So, you could select Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Language->C++ Language Standard and set ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17).

Secondly, you could add `std::` before vector and `;` after `return i`.

Finally , if you use vector,int>>, you could change `cells.push_back({ x, y }, 0);` to `cells.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x, y), 0));` and change `cells[i][0] == { x, y }` to `cells.at[i].first.first == x&& cells.at[i].first.second==y`.